# Lycoris models fail in Stable Diffusion with error "size of tensor a (768) must match size of tensor b (1024)

Tags: runtime-error

I am using AUTOMATIC111/stable-diffusion-webui on my PC (Window 10, Intel Cor i9, 64GB RAM, Nvidia RTX 3060).  I have successfully installed the LoRA and LyCORIS extensions in Stable Diffusion, and both have tabs in Extra Networks. All of the LoRA models that I have downloaded from civiai.com work, but only one of the 10 LyCORIS models work.  For example, colouredglazecd-000006.safetensors works.  I got this image using img2img with a picture of a pink rose and the prompt: lyco:colouredglazecd-000006:1.0rose. [glazed rose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV0ua.png)

However, when I try to use  lyco:CenturyBotanicalIllustration:1.0rose or any of the other 9 Lycoris models I downloaded, I get the error message:  RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (768) must match the size of tensor b (1024) at non-singleton dimension 1.  Below is a sample of the beginning of the webui-user.bat output and a sample from the end of the code.  Changing the width or height of the output image doesn't help.  Any help with this will be greatly appreciated

Zaffer

Code from beginning of webui-user.bat

```
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_mlp_fc1.alpha████████████████| 16/16 [00:06<00:00,  3.09it/s]
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_mlp_fc1.lora_down.weight
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_mlp_fc1.lora_up.weight
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_mlp_fc2.alpha
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_mlp_fc2.lora_down.weight
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_mlp_fc2.lora_up.weight
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_self_attn_k_proj.alpha
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_self_attn_k_proj.lora_down.weight
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_self_attn_k_proj.lora_up.weight
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_self_attn_out_proj.alpha
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_self_attn_out_proj.lora_down.weight
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_self_attn_out_proj.lora_up.weight
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_self_attn_q_proj.alpha
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_self_attn_q_proj.lora_down.weight
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_self_attn_q_proj.lora_up.weight
key failed to match: lora_te_text_model_encoder_layers_12_self_attn_v_proj.alpha

Code from end of webui-user.bat
File "G:\GenAI\venv\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\clip\modeling_clip.py", line 268, in forward
        query_states = self.q_proj(hidden_states) * self.scale
      File "G:\GenAI\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
        return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
      File "G:\GenAI\extensions-builtin\Lora\lora.py", line 400, in lora_Linear_forward
        return torch.nn.Linear_forward_before_lora(self, input)
      File "G:\GenAI\extensions\a1111-sd-webui-lycoris\lycoris.py", line 739, in lyco_Linear_forward
        lyco_apply_weights(self)
      File "G:\GenAI\extensions\a1111-sd-webui-lycoris\lycoris.py", line 706, in lyco_apply_weights
        self.weight += updown
    RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (768) must match the size of tensor b (1024) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your locon model based different SD model. Let's say your trying to create image with sd v1.5 and your locon (or lycoris) model is based sd v2.1